# Existing cucumber bdd steps do not work with Karate

Tags: cucumber, bdd, karate

I have recently started using karate. I have an existing project which has steps with cucumber and now I am writing tests using karate. As Karate is built on cucumber, I am still not able to run my custom written step definitions.

I tried adding all cucumber and karate dependencies, adding cucumber option in karateRunner

NA

com.intuit.karate.exception.KarateException: KarateTesting.feature:14 - no step-definition method match found for: Then verify the transaction calculation and logic

Comment: It depends on the version and what you are doing etc. Read this ticket for more details: https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/444#issuecomment-419852761 If the above does not help, please follow this process: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue